# Обращение к значениям LIstView программным путем

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Есть ListView (WPF) который который заполняется следующим образом: 
XAML:

```
<ListView Name="LV_Beantragung" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,10" Grid.Row="2" Width="500" Height="130" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionChanged="LV_Beantragung_SelectionChanged">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Templ">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding}" Width="240"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource Templ}" Header="Von" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DatumVon}"/>
            <GridViewColumn HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource Templ}" Header="Bis" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DatumBis}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
```

Заполняется он  следующим образом

```
LV_Beantragung.Items.Add(new { DatumVon = d1.ToShortDateString(), DatumBis = d2.ToShortDateString()});
```

Как можно обратится к значению `LV_Beantragung.SelectedItems[0]` - DatumVon или DatumBis напрямую?? что-то типа `LV_Beantragung.SelectedItems[0].DatumVon` не работает. А если брать значение LV_Beantragung.SelectedItems[0] напрямую то нужно вырезать "DatumVon=" и "DatumBis=".

[image: Debugger screenshot]

Comment: 1) Почему вы используете анонимные классы? 2) Почему не завести нормальную коллекцию и привязать ее в `ItemsSource`? Этого топика вообще бы не возникло.

Answer (score 0):

Переделал на коллекцию...в смысле Dictionary....так как в каждой строке две даты...и лист не подходит так как одномерный и если сделать объект типа например:

```
public class tmpDates 
{ 
public DateTime DatumVon { get; set; } 
public DateTime DatumBis { get; set; } 
}
```

то в ListView стоит не даты а ссылка на объект. А если Dictionary то выглядит тоже "Интересно":

[image: Screenshot]

То есть обе даты в столбец...

Comment: Попробуйте использовать не DateTime, а string в вашем новом классе. Приводите дату к строке также, как делали это раньше, с анонимным классом

Answer (score 0):

Все получилось....ошибка была в XAML, я убрал у ListView "Binding Patch" поэтому и отображение itemSource было неверным. Сейчас выглядит так:

```
<ListView Name="LV_Beantragung" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,10" Grid.Row="2" Width="500" Height="130" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionChanged="LV_Beantragung_SelectionChanged">
  <ListView.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Templ">
      <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding}" Width="240"/>
    </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.Resources>
<ListView.View>
  <GridView>
    <GridViewColumn HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource Templ}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=DatumVon, StringFormat='dd-MM-yyyy'}" Header="Von" />
    <GridViewColumn HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource Templ}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=DatumBis, StringFormat='dd-MM-yyyy'}" Header="Bis" />
   </GridView>
 </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

ну и соответственно на С#:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

    public class LVOneZeile
    {
     public DateTime DatumVon { get; set; }
     public DateTime DatumBis { get; set; }
     }

ObservableCollection<LVOneZeile> LVSource = new ObservableCollection<LVOneZeile>();

......

LVSource.Add(new LVOneZeile{ DatumVon = dFirstDate, DatumBis = dEndDate });

.......

LV_Beantragung.ItemsSource = LVSource;
```

Всем спасибо за подсказки!